# *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer: 0x00050530 *** & coredump & no valgrind on ARMv5

Tags: gdb, glibc, coredump

I have

```
*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer: 0x00050530 ***
```

and coredump

```
(gdb) bt
#0  memcpy () at ../sysdeps/arm/memcpy.S:93
#1  0x40025188 in __free_tcb (pd=0x0) at pthread_create.c:217
#2  0x5927f3a0 in ?? ()

(gdb) p 0x00050530
$4 = 329008
```

and no valgrind because of platform restriction ARMv5

what useful info can i get form coredump and that address?

Comment: ok electricfence works on my platform

Comment: uh but unable to run it with my big app